# How to instantiate properties in the ctor of an object with Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

I have POCO object MyObject

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyProperty MyProperty001 { get; set; }
    public MyProperty MyProperty002 { get; set; }


    MyModel()
    {
        // New up all the public properties
        var properties = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            //Activator.CreateInstance()
        }
    }
}
```

that has hundreds of properties, is it possible using reflection to instantiate these in the constructor? I have the PropertyInfo, but don't know what is the next step.

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: You create instances of objects, not properties.

Comment: What do you mean by "new up"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type of property holds within of `PropertyType` property of `PropertyInfo` object, so according to that you can instantiate your objects by calling `Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType)`. Than you need to set instance into property of your container object by calling `propertyInfo.SetValue(this, instance, null)`

Full sample:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in properties) 
{
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyInfo.PropertyType);
    propertyInfo.SetValue(this, instance, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyModel
{
    private MyProperty _MyProperty001 = new MyProperty();
    public MyProperty MyProperty001 
    { 
      get { return _myProperty001; } 
      set { _MyProperty001 = value; }
    }
}
```

Use a backing field, no need for reflection.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer, there's no need to do this through reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to set the property value to a new instance of the according property type, this should be possible the following way:

```
var instance = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(new object[0]);
propertyInfo.SetValue(this, instance, null);
```

Comment: as long as there's a default constructor for that type

Answer (score 0):

If they are no parameter constructors, you could do

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in properties) {
    ConstructorInfo ci = propertyInfo.GetType().GetConstructor(new Type[] { propertyInfo.PropertyType() });
     propertyInfo.SetValue(this, ci.Invoke(new object[] { }), null);
 }
```

Comment: Third parameter of `propertyInfo.SetValue` should be null if property is not indexer

Comment: Not sure whether `propertyInfo.GetType()` returns the correct type. Usually it should return just `PropertyInfo`. `propertyInfo.PropertyType` is the right way to go.